# Update lightning:inputField when fieldName updated

Tags: lightning-inputfield

I'm using lightning:recordEditForm and lightning:inputField to create new record. But I want to setup my field is automatically:

```
<lightning:inputField fieldName="{! v.myField}" value="{! v.myValue}" />
```

But when I set myField to another field with the same fieldType, my inputField not change. 
I found a solution but I think it's not correct: I set myField to null before and after that, using timeout to set myField to new Field:

```
cmp.set("v.myField", null);
window.setTimeout(
    $A.getCallback(function() {
         cmp.set("v.myField", "newField");
    }), 1000
);
```

What's the best solution or what wrong I met ?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean when you say:-  I want to setup my field is automatically: and when I set myField to another field with the same fieldType, my inputField not change?

Comment: Example: Object MyObject__c has two field: FirstName__c, LastName__c. In init, I set myField = FirstName__c => render inputField right. After that, I do an action, like a click a button, or checkbox, ... and that action's purpose is change myField to LastName__c. Basically we use cmp.set("v.myField", "LastName__c"); But inputField not change.